# R: Writing loops to replace NULL with Dates

Tags: r, loops

The Here is an example of my table:

```
custID | StartDate | EndDate   | ReasonForEnd  | TransactionType | TransactionDate
    1a |  NULL     | 2/12/2014 | AccountClosed |  AccountOpened  |  1/15/2004
    1a |  NULL     | 2/12/2014 | AccountClosed |  Purchase       |  3/16/2004
    .......
    2b | 7/7/2011  | 6/14/2013 | AccountClosed | AccountOpened   |  8/1/2010
```

The problem has to do with the `StartDate` field. For each `custId`, if the entry is NULL then I want to replace with the `TransactionDate` where `TransactionType = AccountOpened`. If `StartDate` is after the `TransactionDate` where `TransactionType = AccountOpened`, then replace with this date.

The actual data is over 250,000 rows. I really need some help figuring out how to write this in R.

Comment: somehow I think you are trying to tacle this in an SQLish stile... if so, you should check the [`sqldf`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) package

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following, however I didn't test it yet. I assume your data.frame is called `df`:

```
require(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate_each(funs(as.Date(as.character(., format="%m/%d/%Y"))), 
                StartDate, EndDate, TransactionDate) %>%
    group_by(custID) %>%
    mutate(StartDate = ifelse(is.na(StartDate) | StartDate > TransactionDate[TransactionType == "AccountOpened"], 
                          TransactionDate[TransactionType == "AccountOpened"], StartDate))
```

This code first converts several columns to `Date` format (in this step, NULL entries will be converted to NA), groups by `custID` and then checks if `StartDate` is either `NA` or greater than `TransactionDate` where `TransactionType == "AccountOpened"` and if TRUE, replaces `StartDate` with `TransactionDate` where `TransactionType == "AccountOpened"`.